# ASP.NET 'FindByIdAsync' returns values but not passing values to variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, razor-pages, roles

I am trying to edit a list of Roles that I created via a Create page. However when I try to retrieve the role to edit using the FindByIdAsync(id), the role value/data is not being passed to the variable. The variable "role" is returning null and I don't understand why since I am retrieving the data successfully. Why is this happening?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using ThreeTierAdvisementApp.Data;

namespace ThreeTierAdvisementApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Administration
{

    public class EditRole : PageModel
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly UserManager<DefaultUser> userManager;

        public EditRole(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<DefaultUser> userManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            this.userManager = userManager;
            Users = new List<string>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Role Name is Required")]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        public List<string> Users { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public IList<EditRole> CurrentRoles { get; set; }


        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(string id)
        {

            var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (role == null)
            {

                return NotFound();
            }

            var model = new EditRoles
            {
                Id = role.Id,
                RoleName = role.Name,
            };

            foreach (var user in userManager.Users)
            {
                if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
                {
                    model.Users.Add(user.UserName);
                };
            }
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
    }
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ThreeTierAdvisementApp.Data
{
    public class EditRoles:IdentityRole
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Role Name is required")]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        public List<string> Users { get; set; }
    }
}

**Identity Class**
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace ThreeTierAdvisementApp.Data
{
    public class DefaultUser:IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }
}

**Role Class**
    public class Roles : IdentityRole
    {
        [Required]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
    }




**List of rolse view. When I click the edit button I want to edit the selected role**
@page
@using ThreeTierAdvisementApp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Administration
@model ListRoleModel;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "All Roles";
}


<h1>All Roles</h1>
@if(Model.CurrentRoles.Any()){
@foreach (var item in Model.CurrentRoles)
    {

        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleName)</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a asp-page="EditRole" asp-route-Id="@Model.CurrentRoles" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
                <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    }
}else{
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h2>No Roles Yet</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">
                Use the button below to create a role
            </h5>
        </div>
        <a class="w-25 btn btn-lg btn-primary" asp-page="CreateRole">Create Role</a>

</div>
}






@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Comment: There is no enough info to provide a definite answer. Have you checked that correct id is passed to `string id`  parameter?

Comment: Yeah I believe correct id is being passed

Comment: I my Identity and role classes as well as my list view. Hope its a bit clearer now

Comment: @GuruStron silly me just needed to restart my database. Thanks for the input.